# SPAQRL: select item and count occurences of its label

Tags: duplicates, sparql, rdf

I have [this SPARQL query](https://www.orkg.org/orkg/triplestore?query=%0APREFIX%20orkgr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fresource%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20orkgc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fclass%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20orkgp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fpredicate%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fo1Label%20(COUNT(%3Fo1Label)%20AS%20%3Fo1LabelCount)%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fo1%20a%20orkgc%3APaper.%0A%20%20%3Fo1%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fo1Label.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20(strlen(%3Fo1Label)%20%3E%201).%0A%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fo1Label%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC(%3Fo1LabelCount)%0A%0A) directed to the Open Research Knowledge Graph (ORKG):

```sql
PREFIX orkgr: <http://orkg.org/orkg/resource/>
PREFIX orkgc: <http://orkg.org/orkg/class/>
PREFIX orkgp: <http://orkg.org/orkg/predicate/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?o1Label (COUNT(?o1Label) AS ?o1LabelCount)
WHERE {
  ?o1 a orkgc:Paper.
  ?o1 rdfs:label ?o1Label.
  
  FILTER (strlen(?o1Label) > 1).
}

GROUP BY ?o1Label
ORDER BY DESC(?o1LabelCount)
```

Which results in labels (`?o1Label`) and the number of occurrences of this label (`?o1LabelCount`).

How can I extend this query to also include a column for the actual item (`?o1`)?

Because there might be multiple candidates (when `o1LabelCount` is > 1), there should be one row for each of these items (with the same label and the same label count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

First (and probably better) is to use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggGroupConcat) and collect the entities into one field to be parsed again on application side. this could look like this ([link](https://www.orkg.org/orkg/triplestore?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20orkgr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20orkgc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fclass%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20orkgp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fpredicate%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fo1Label%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28%3Fo1%2C%20%22%5Ct%22%29%20AS%20%3Fo1s%29%20%28COUNT%28%3Fo1Label%29%20AS%20%3Fo1LabelCount%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fo1%20a%20orkgc%3APaper.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fo1%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fo1Label.%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28strlen%28%3Fo1Label%29%20%3E%201%29.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fo1Label%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fo1LabelCount%29&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)):

```
PREFIX orkgr: <http://orkg.org/orkg/resource/>
PREFIX orkgc: <http://orkg.org/orkg/class/>
PREFIX orkgp: <http://orkg.org/orkg/predicate/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?o1Label (GROUP_CONCAT(?o1, "\t") AS ?o1s) (COUNT(?o1Label) AS ?o1LabelCount)
WHERE {
  ?o1 a orkgc:Paper.
  ?o1 rdfs:label ?o1Label.
  
  FILTER (strlen(?o1Label) > 1).
}

GROUP BY ?o1Label
ORDER BY DESC(?o1LabelCount)
```

---

An alternative would be using [nested queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#subqueries) and receive a result as you described ([link](https://www.orkg.org/orkg/triplestore?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20orkgr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20orkgc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fclass%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20orkgp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Forkg.org%2Forkg%2Fpredicate%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fo1Label%20%3Fo1%20%3Fo1LabelCount%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fo1%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fo1Label%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fo1Label%20%28COUNT%28%3Fo1Label%29%20AS%20%3Fo1LabelCount%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20orkgc%3APaper%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fo1Label%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28strlen%28%3Fo1Label%29%20%3E%201%29.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fo1Label%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fo1LabelCount%29&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)):

```
PREFIX orkgr: <http://orkg.org/orkg/resource/>
PREFIX orkgc: <http://orkg.org/orkg/class/>
PREFIX orkgp: <http://orkg.org/orkg/predicate/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?o1Label ?o1 ?o1LabelCount
WHERE {
  ?o1 rdfs:label ?o1Label .

  {
    SELECT ?o1Label (COUNT(?o1Label) AS ?o1LabelCount)
    WHERE {
      [
        a orkgc:Paper;
        rdfs:label ?o1Label
      ]
      FILTER (strlen(?o1Label) > 1).
    }
  }
}

GROUP BY ?o1Label
ORDER BY DESC(?o1LabelCount)
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Thanks. However, it seems that the link to the GROUP_CONCAT documentation is broken.

Comment: Should be fixed now.